# Having trouble with finding x-ray weight paint function in newer version

Tags: animation, weight-painting

So I have having been learning all the differences in versions of blender since 2.8. Now I’m stumped about having the x-ray function in weight painting in version 2.83. I have been looking for an answer but all I can find is people saying turn on 2d falloff, but it seems to have been removed since the version that was being used when the answers were given. The answers show pictures of where the toggle for 2d fall off can be found and not only is the toggle not there in my version, but the menu its in is very different in my version.
Please help me out, I’m stuck with a weight paint issue that seems it can only be solved by the x-ray function.
Why did they have to go and mess around with the UI that was in 2.7.9 when they just make things much more complicated and harder to navigate.

Comment: Sorry, what happens if you go to weight-paint mode, turn on X-Ray, and select Wireframe preview? Is this close to what you're looking for?

Comment: In version 2.8 and beyond, the x-ray button seems to do nothing, even with wireframe. I read things about now having to use 2d falloff, but it doesn't seem to exist in 2.8.3. Again why do they try to improve the UI and just make it far harder to use?

Comment: I read that in the new version you have to change the falloff shape setting from sphere to project but it did nothing for me despite then guy asking saying it did for him.